# Alternatives to cron jobs

Tags: php, video, cron

I have a website where users can upload videos. I currently use a cron job to run a php script every 5 minutes to check if any videos needs processing.

A couple of notes;

- I don't want to just run the script more often.
- I'm not limited by number of servers / cost / programming languages or technology.

I'd like videos to be processed instantly without having to wait 5 minutes. **I want to get rid of cron jobs**, they just don't feel right. **How can I achieve this?**

It feels like PHP + crons are the wrong choice for this and I need a process always listening for new uploads. Surely YouTube don't use cron jobs?

Comment: You need to make them feel right because they're almost always the right tool for the job

Comment: @JohnConde I strongly disagree with that statement.

Comment: @JohnConde surely not? Big services surely can't use them?

Comment: Make a deamon http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29

Comment: Why can't your file upload handling code signal the processing system that something new is available? It's not hard: `handle_upload(); start_new_background_processing_job($uploaded_file)`.

Comment: Something like Gearman for back-end processing?